# Executing jar file throws class not found error

Tags: java

Using Eclipse, I am modifying a Java project we have been using for years. a specific class method is typically executed by sending a message through IBM WebSphere MQ. However, I now have a need to develop some new functionality and I need to be able to test it out side the MQ world.

I am able to successfully debug the application in Eclipse, but if I attempt to execute the jar file from a command prompt I receive the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: XMLBuilder/Node
>  
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>  
>   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source) 
>   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XMLBuilder.Node 
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   ... 6 more

My build is done using an ant script. This does not include a Class-Path attribute when creating the manifest.

The XMLBuilder.jar file is included in the target jar. Running jar -tf file.jar shows

> META-INF/)
>   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
>   ... Omitted for Brevity ...
>   XMLBuilder.jar

What might I be missing?

Thank you

Comment: Is the class you want inside of *that* JAR?

Comment: Yes. However, not sure how to say this, that jar (XMLBuilder) has no exported classes. So there is no import statement. It's usage is simply XMLBuilder.document.

Comment: Probably your XMLBuilder.jar file should live outside of your executable jar and you would reference it via an entry in the MANIFEST.MF file--probably use a relative path will be easiest. Am thinking you'd need a custom class loader if you want to pull classes from a jar within a jar--seems like it would be painful. You might investigate things like Maven's Shade plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or Jar Jar Links (https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).